# Apache Virtual Hosts with a Wildcard DNS Record

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

Here is my current setup:

At the bottom of `httpd.conf` I have the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Include /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/*
```

Inside of `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts` I have the following files:

mainsite.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/mainsite.com"
  ServerName mainsite.com
  ServerAlias www.mainsite.com
  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mainsite.com">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

sub1.mainsite.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/sub1.mainsite.com
  ServerName sub1.mainsite.com
  <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/sub1.mainsite.com">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So far so good! `mainsite.com` and `www.mainsite.com` both share the same `DocumentRoot` (and with some redirection later I can redirect all `www.mainsite.com` users to `mainsite.com` for SEO). `sub1.mainsite.com` also has its own `DocumentRoot` and doesn't interfere with anything else.

However, `<Anything that isn't www or sub1>.mainsite.com` gets the same `DocumentRoot` that `mainsite.com` and `www.mainsite.com` get. What I would prefer instead is an error page to come up for any host that doesn't match a `VirtualHost`.

**And now for the actual question:**
What can I tweak to get the desired effect? Also, can the directory rules that are common between the `VirtualHost`s be refactored up into `httpd.conf`? If so, would I just do something like the following?

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts">
  allow from all
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *.mainsite.com
...
... 
</VirtualHost>
```

Should catch anything that isn't otherwise defined.

Comment: Just make sure this config is read last so that the other sites aren't effected.

Answer (score 2):

I use a catchall vhost definition that is the last to be read

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      default
        ServerAlias *
        DocumentRoot /var/www/default
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
        <Directory "/var/www/default">
            Options All
            AllowOverride None
            allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The default index.html file tells the user that there is noting to see at the address supplied. The 404.html file same.